# Angular 4 - ASP.Net Core - Compiling error

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular

After having ejected webpack.config.js I use to compile my Angular project using  the command: **npm run build**, lately while launched the build I got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/share' 
in 'C:\...\node_modules@angular\c ore@angular' 
@ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 9:0-44 
@ ./ClientApp/main.ts @ multi ./ClientApp/main.ts
```

Modules versions are as next:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.9 (e)
node: 6.11.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
@ngtools/webpack: 1.7.4
typescript: 2.7.0-dev.20171031
```

and here is the npm-debug log:

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js', verbose cli   'run', verbose cli   'build' ]
info using npm@3.10.10
info using node@v6.11.3
verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
info lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~prebuild: ng2-asp-core@0.0.0
silly lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
info lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: ng2-asp-core@0.0.0
verbose lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
verbose lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;..............etc ......
verbose lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: CWD: C:\MyApp
silly lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack' ]
silly lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
info lifecycle ng2-asp-core@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
verbose stack Error: ng2-asp-core@0.0.0 build: `webpack` verbose stack Exit status 2 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16) verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7) verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14) verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16) verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
verbose pkgid ng2-asp-core@0.0.0
verbose cwd C:\MyApp
error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
error node v6.11.3
error npm  v3.10.10
error code ELIFECYCLE
error ng2-asp-core@0.0.0 build: `webpack` error Exit status 2
error Failed at the ng2-asp-core@0.0.0 build script 'webpack'.
error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ng2-asp-core package, error not with npm itself. error Tell the author that this fails on your system: error     webpack error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: error     npm bugs ng2-asp-core error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: error     npm owner ls ng2-asp-core error There is likely additional logging output above.
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

As the debug log points to ng2-asp-core package as error source, I have run the command **npm owner ls ng2-asp-core** to get the owner but got a 404 error: **ng2-asp-core' is not in the npm registry**^

Update: Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ng2-asp-core",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.7.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.66",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "~3.7.1",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.7.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't have `rxjs` installed so you should run `npm install rxjs` to fix.

Comment: Failed at the ng2-asp-core@0.0.0 build script 'webpack', same as before

Comment: can you put your `package.json` file up? To me it sounds like you might have a version/dep conflict.

Comment: put `"rxjs": "^5.0.1",` in the package json dependencies then run `npm install`

Comment: still getting the same error, is it normal to have 0.0.0 as version of ng2-asp-core ?